# ExpressJS not redirecting configured PATH

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

I am setting up a local proxy to redirect specific URLs to another server, I am running my expressJS server as my main server, I have another server running on a different port... My express JS config is as follows

```
const express = require('express');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const API_URL = "<http://localhost:8989>";

app.get("/status", (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('This is a proxy service');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});
app.use(express.static('dist'))

const proxyOptions = {
    target: API_URL,
    changeOrigin: true
}

const proxy = createProxyMiddleware(proxyOptions);

app.use('/?access', proxy)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Proxy Started at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
});
```

I want any URL starting with `/?access` to redirect to the other server `localhost:8989` BUT keep the `/?access...` intact so it can submit that information to the new server. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I am using FETCH to send the information I need

```
fetch('/?access=myAccessToken&action=off')
```

it is also worth noting that I get 304 in the browser console.

I managed to configure `app.use('/?access', proxy)` as per ExpressJS docs, and have also also consulted the http-proxy-middleware documentation and, tried a quick Google to help resolve the issue, but nothing was helpful...

I have tried adding the URL to a standard link (a href) and I still get the same issue.

```
<a href="/?access=myAccessToken&action=off">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: for clarity.

When you write:

```js
app.use('/?access'
```

the `?` in the url will tell express to match the route

```js
/access
```

It is not the literal `?`.

But in your front-end code you are using it to mean [query parameter](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/query-parameters) so your link:

```html
<a href="/?access=myAccessToken&action=off">Click Me</a>
```

Is going to be routed to the `/` path with a query parameter key of `access`. It will therefore just be picked up by the `/` route handler on port `8080` and not proxied. For example:

```html
http://localhost:8080/?access=myAccessToken&action=off
```

I think what would help you achieve the desired outcome would be to have your route to proxy be something simple like `/auth` which would then look like:

```js
app.use('/auth', proxy)
```

Now when you navigate to:

```html
<a href="/auth?access=myAccessToken&action=off">Click Me</a>
```

The request will be proxied to:

```html
http://localhost:8989/auth?access=myAccessToken&action=off
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I have changed it slightly to strip the AUTRH bit out so `app.use('/auth', proxy)` becomes `app.use('^/auth', proxy)` as the server on the other end requires the request in the original format

Comment: That looks ok. I have updated the answer to make my explanation a bit clearer too.